# Kafka Data Center Failover

Tags: apache-kafka

I'm looking into options for managing a complete data centre failover when a Kafka cluster spans 2 DC's, whilst guaranteeing availability of partitions after the fact. Having the cluster span DC's is preferable to us over the added complexity of Mirrormaker/Replicator and we have a high-speed link available between the two to reduce latency.

Kafka has the concept of rack awareness so the replicas of a topic will be automatically spread between both racks, however I am struggling to see a configuration of replication/min-isr that will not result in less availability/data loss after a rack failover.

Assuming the below simplest scenario, I am looking for a configuration that can handle complete loss of rack 1 without making partitions unavailable/causing data loss (potentially at cost of higher latency if needed):

- 4 brokers across 2 racks
- Replication = 4
- Min in-sync replicas = 2
- Producer ack=all

Everything works fine when all 4 replicas are kept in-sync with acks=all, however because min in-sync replicas is set to 2, there could be the case where both ISR's are in rack 1 only? In the event of a complete rack 1 failure, there would be no ISR's/leader at all so no messages could be produced/read from the topic?

```
Broker    DC/Rack   Topic Replica
1          1         1 (in sync)
2          1         2 (in sync)  <-- min.insync.replicas=2 + acks=all compatible
3          2         3 (out of sync)
4          2         4 (out of sync)  <-- not 2 ISR's in rack 2
```

Am I missing something or is there some other configuration which will allow for a complete rack failure? Is managing a complete rack failure without the risk of unclean elections or lower availablility possible with Kafka?

Comment: I'm not sure min ISR knows about racks, so I'd set it to 3 with 4 replicas and all acks

Comment: As far as I can tell that wouldn't help either as with min_isync replicas set to 3 there would never be enough replicas available if rack 1 went down - only max of 2 in rack 2, so wouldn't be able to produce to that partition

Answer (score 1):

for a 4 broker cluster stretched over two DCs in order to prevent data loss and survive one DC failure you’ll have to:

1. set ISR to 3 to ensure at least one copy of data exists in each DC
2. set replication factor to 4
3. when one DC fails then manually reduce ISR to 2 to allow producer writes and scale it back to 3 when failed DC recovers.

Note:

- from what I know rack awareness does not guarantee partition replication cross different racks, but rather operates on a best effort basis;
- scaling up the above topology might not work well because of extra IO; in case you need to increase the cluster to 6 brokers (to scale reads/writes) then you’ll need ISR = 4, replication factor >= 5

Answer (score 0):

> scaling up the above topology might not work well because of extra IO;
> in case you need to increase the cluster to 6 brokers (to scale
> reads/writes) then you’ll need ISR = 4, replication factor >= 5

Why can't we use `replication factor >= 4`  ?